# Stay Login even after application is closed c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I was trying to login Using Microsoft SQL to manage the data. When I login, it logins but when I close the application and open it again  it ask to login. Then I tried to make a xml to store the account details but it was less secure. Best Example like steam. It doesn't logout until the user wanted to logout.

```
 private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string LoginQuery = "Select * from Account where UserID='" + txtusername.Text.Trim() + "' and Password='" + txtpassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(LoginQuery,SqlCon);
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        SDA.Fill(DT);
        if (DT.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            //Do login Stuff
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invaild Username and Password.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you manage the authentication yourself, you can do whatever you want. So if you want to store the login state you have to do so in the "//do login Stuff" section and whatever you do there, you have to check for it on the next application start.
But this kind of auth handling seems quite rudimentary and storing the password plain text ist really a bad idea.

Comment: Thats what I'm thinking to auto login when I open the application if previous was logged in. Don't know where to start it

Comment: Systems like Steam likely use popular authentication schemes such as OAuth2 which, after a login, issue a time-limited "token" - i.e. a unique code specific to that login session, whose validity expires after a certain period of time. Depending on the implementation, the client may then be allowed to use a "refresh token" to extend the login period a bit longer, or the user may have to log in again with their credentials as soon as it expires. Storing the token, unique and time-limited as it is, in your application is generally considered safer than directly storing the user's credentials.

Comment: P.S. Your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - learn to use parameterised queries, please. In fact, it's even vulnerable just to basic syntax issues. If I used a `'` in my password for example (which ought to be a legitimate thing to do), your query would simply crash because the `'` would mess up the SQL syntax, making it thing the input string ends earlier than it does. Using parameters avoids this problem, you don't have to worry about quote marks at all. So there's another reason to write your queries properly!

Comment: Also, you should not be storing passwords in plain text, that's another security risk. Learn about password  hashing.